# JasperReports Dynamic Grouping

Tags: jasper-reports

sorry for opening this question.i would like to somebody tell me how to archive this because a i have the same problem but i don't get the desired results or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587511/jasperreports-grouping-changeable-by-user?answertab=oldest#tab-top) question presumes its possible but i don't get the same.

and i shall continue with my work

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="detailVisitShop" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" scriptletClass="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet" uuid="4c82ee8a-2708-4b04-a1f3-b213d6c4c380">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="Title" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Times-Bold"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#736343" fontName="Arial" fontSize="18"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Arial" fontSize="12" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" fontName="Arial" fontSize="16"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#E6DAC3"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="idCliente" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[3]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="grpHeader" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
    Cv.condicionventaname 'CondicionVenta',
    concat(Cl.`names`, ' ', Cl.lastnames) 'Cliente',
    U.userName 'Operador',
    V.fecha,
    V.Total,V.idventa,v.cliente_idcliente,
    case
        when Cv.idcondicionventa = 1 then concat('Folio ', cast(V.folio as char))
        else concat('Factura ', cast(V.factura as char))
    end as 'Numero de operacion',
    case
        when V.cars_numberplate is not null then concat('Placas ' , V.cars_numberplate)
        when V.climas_idclimas  is not null then concat('Numero de serie ', V.climas_idclimas)
    end as 'Servicio A', V.cars_numberplate placas,V.climas_idclimas clima,U.userName 
from
    Ventas V
        left join
    Climas cli ON Cli.idclimas = V.climas_idclimas
        left join
    Cars ca ON Ca.numberplate = V.cars_numberplate
        left join
    condicionventa Cv ON Cv.idcondicionventa = V.condicionventa_idcondicionventa
       inner join
    cliente Cl ON Cl.idcliente = V.cliente_idcliente
        inner join
    users U ON U.iduser = V.Users_idUser
order by $P{grpHeader}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CondicionVenta" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Cliente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Operador" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fecha" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
    <field name="Total" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    <field name="idventa" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="cliente_idcliente" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Numero de operacion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Servicio A" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="placas" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="clima" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="userName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="variable1" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Total}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="groupVal" class="java.lang.Object">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{grpHeader}.equals("Placas") ? 
            $F{placas} : ($P{grpHeader}.equals("cliente") ? $F{Cliente} : $F{Cliente} )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="numberOfVisits" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Group1" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{idventa}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$P{grpHeader}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="37">
                <frame>
                    <reportElement uuid="b6aeacfd-18df-4b4e-8d03-b205cd4e0509" mode="Opaque" x="-21" y="7" width="843" height="24" forecolor="#B89F7D" backcolor="#F2EBDF"/>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement uuid="87ff53e3-0507-4a1a-983d-c25f21767513" style="SubTitle" x="68" y="0" width="755" height="24" forecolor="#736343"/>
                        <textElement>
                            <font isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{placas}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </frame>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="26">
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement uuid="0a5f2335-ad9e-4a8c-8b77-0a2f5ffcfb2d" mode="Opaque" x="-1" y="0" width="802" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#838E8E"/>
                </rectangle>
                <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="7fb963f9-825a-498f-9635-98614f1f0893" x="559" y="5" width="202" height="20" forecolor="#FFCC00"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{variable1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="19e30ce4-bcd7-4763-87c8-20f95a64461a" x="459" y="0" width="100" height="25"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <font size="16"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="¤ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="06e8276f-7143-4c0e-ad9f-336fabbead33" x="1" y="0" width="171" height="25"/>
                    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="16"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Numero de vistas"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="e22bb9e4-770e-45cf-b4eb-30d7a0c50633" x="195" y="6" width="202" height="20"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{numberOfVisits}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
```

also i checked other sources like [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/jasperreports-questions@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00239.html) but i couldn't accomplish my goal. so this is impossible or i' doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If You want't to change SQL statement with parameter, syntax for parameter is a bit different.
In your example change the order by part into this:

```
order by $P!{grpHeader}
```

Without the "!" after $P Jasper will insert formatted value, so in run time you would get something like

```
order by "cliente"
```

instead of

```
order by cliente
```

Group by expression looks OK, do you get any errors when you run the report (after correcting order by clause)?

Comment: sir i get no groups, i made up the changes i believe i can't get it rigth in any ways i leave it just like this and try dynamic reports